# Search all sub-folders for .mp3 files

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

I know the parent folder that will contain these mp3 files I am looking for, but I have allot of sub-folders in it.

How can I search for all files and sub-folders for files ending with .mp3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `find` terminal command. Open Terminal.app (Applications > Utilities > Terminal.app) and run this command:

```
find /path/to/search -name '*.mp3'
```

You need to put the pattern in quotes so that it does not get expanded by the shell.

Comment: And... that's why we (or at least developers) love *nix systems. Just plain English.

Answer (score 5):

As you didn't specify you need a Terminal, you can actually just use the Finder. Enter the parent folder, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, then hit the <kbd>+</kbd> button on the right.

Adjust your settings like seen below. You'll get a list of all MP3 files.

[image]